# Pass "any character" into a PHP value?

Tags: php

***Update:***

*I'm importing an XML feed daily, that is updated every 24h via an XML feed supplier, that gets dumped into our FTP. The file starts with the date, then the time of the export, followed by the rest of the file name.*

*So every day there is a new file added to our FTP, I'm using `date()` to get the days date but the **time** could vary depending on when the server ran export (usually is only off by a minute or so).*

So what I need, is to pass 4 *number* values between the `$date` & `$file` and therefore take the latest file from the necessary folder?

The script joins the multiple values together to create the URL, then sets that value as the `location` in `header();` :

```
<?php

$date = date("Ymd");
$webroot = "http://WEBSITE-URL/";
$file = "-XML-FILE.xml";

$xmlfilelocation = $webroot.$date."0206".$file;

header('Location: '.$xmlfilelocation);

?>
```

The `0206` string is the time, that could vary, is there anyway I can pass any value in there?

Create a `$time = ???;` variable maybe, that is equal to *ANY* 4 characters?

Comment: Why not use $date = date('Ymd'); instead of $year, $month, $day? you can also use $date = date('YmdHi'); H is hours and i is minutes :)

Comment: What is stopping you from doing it?

Comment: Just `rand(0,9999)` it

Comment: I hope I understood what you want ! It is indeed unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've used an alternate approach for this:

```
<?php

//Get web directory
$webdir = "THE-URL";

//Get local directory for scandir
$dir = 'THE-DIRECTORY';

//Create array of file names
$filelist = scandir($dir);

//Count file name and reduce by 1 to account for [0] array item
$recordcount = count($filelist) - 1;

//Get the latest filename from array
$latestfile = $filelist[$recordcount];

//Compile the web directory and filename to create a URL
$xmlfile = $webdir.$latestfile;

//Redirect to necessary URL
header('Location: '.$xmlfile);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function for this. As there might be multiple files, you may want to return the first one :

```
$serverRoot = '/the/real/server/location/';
chdir($serverRoot); // go to the directory where the file is located
$xmlfile = $date."*".$file;
foreach (glob($xmlfile) as $filename) {
    header('Location: '.$webroot.$filename);
    break; // or even exit
}
```

Note : You will have to use the server path for the `glob()` function.

Comment: Inside the `foreach` I'm guessing `$webroot` should be `$serverRoot` in this example?

Comment: No, you want to redirect your user with `http` link ! `glob` works serverside, but the user can't access this folder within a browser, but he can with an http link... If that makes any sens

Comment: I'm confused, where does the `$webroot` value come from then?

Comment: Ah right, so you're *using* $serverRoot and $webroot? What's the difference?

Comment: glob might match `201410091111-XML-FILE.xml` in the `/the/real/server/location/` directory on the server. Then `$filename` contains `201410091111-XML-FILE.xml` and you will redirect to `http://WEBSITE-URL/201410091111-XML-FILE.xml`. Because `glob` does not matches files with http.

Comment: You can get the root directory with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: I've got a feeling this is over-complicating things... I want to return just 1 URL, the URL of the latest XML file, which will ALWAYS begin with todays date, and end with the same file name. Maybe that makes things easier? An "if first 8 characters = todays date", use the file that starts with the date and ends with ".xml" ?

Comment: I've got a feeling that you are over-complicating things ;) This is the easiest way. You just have to understand that when you look for a file, you look for it server side with a real directory `/home/bradadams/www/` for exemple. There is no way to download a file without knowing its exact name. So you have to search it. The `*` is there to say "It could be anything here"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66466/discussion-between-brewal-and-brad-adams).